# Transferring data from listviews across pages

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a listview on the first form of my program which fills up with score data that the user enters. I then have a leaderboard form page which I want to fill up with this score information in order from lowest to highest. Is there a way to copy the information from the list on the first form to the second?

Comment: Yes, what have you tried? If you're stuck beyond even an attempt, I would suggest doing a search for `passing data between forms` and work from there.

Comment: Hi Emly, can you provide us more details? Is it WPF, Windows Forms? Maybe some small bits of your code. Also, in VB.NET you can use a Module.

Comment: Unless you need the grouping capabilities of the ListView you may want to switch to a DataGrdView which can be bound to a datatable. Much easier to move the data that way.